# Opening form to specific record: Object required

Tags: vba, ms-access, button

I am trying to open a form, from a button, to a particular record by primary key. The value of the primary key I want to open the form to is in a text box named [MainLinkStoff] next to the button. There is a main form called [HUB] and a navigation subform on it. The button and the textbox are both on that navigation subform. I got the reference for the textbox using the expression generator, so it should work. In fact, when plugging the expresion into another textbox somehwere else, it does. The name of the form I want to open is [neusdb]. Hardcoding in the value for the primary key works too. When I run the button, I get:

> Runtime error '424':

> Object required

The code for my button is as follows:

```
Private Sub command_new_sdb_copy_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "neusdb", , , "stoff_id=" & Forms![HUB]![NavigationSubform].Form![MainLinkStoff]

End Sub
```

I know I can use a shorter handle for the reference, since the button is located on the same form as the text box. Both versions result in the same error though.

My Database:

[image]

Comment: If the button and the textbox are on the same form, try `Me.MainLinkStoff.Value`.

Comment: That does appear to work. And using `Parent` in a subform does too. Maybe the expression generator is just wrong. But I don't get why it would then work as the `Control Source` of another textbox. Or does `DoCmd.OpenForm` not accept the same input?

Comment: It's a matter of resolving the reference really, not sure what's wrong. Regarding the Parent, keep in mind because subforms are always loaded first, it could throw an error based on usage.

Comment: As in the Parent is not yet loaded when the subform calls the reference?

Comment: Indeed. If for example you reference the Parent property on the Load event of a subform, the parent form has not been loaded yet so it will be null and will throw a null reference error.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. I think I found the issue, which is likely also the cause of many of my other issues. I was working on the project from 2 different pc's. One had the English version of access and the other was in German (work).  The german version uses different expressions for certain things, especially in the SQL codes. It auto generates code like `Formulare` for Forms and `Formular` for Form etc. A few other things too. That seems to have messed up referencing in the file. Switching all the random german formulations to english seems to have fixed almost everything.